# SignalR on new relic it's on top of error rate with this request: [host]/signalr/connect/

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, azure, signalr

I have a Sitefinity app hosted in Azure CloudService and I use signalr to push data to clients. Recently monitoring the app with new relic I found that the signalr its on top of error rate with this request: [host]/signalr/connect/ as you may see in the image. Also say that push work perfectly.

[capture of error rate in newrelic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tptc7.png)

My Server side:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace SitefinityWebApp.FXS.Custom.AppStart
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new SignalRErrorHandler());

        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        };

        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    }
}
}

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Hubs.Posts
{
    public class PostHub : Hub
    {
    }

public class PostNotification : IPostNotification
{
    private readonly static Lazy<PostNotification> instance = new Lazy<PostNotification>(() => new PostNotification());

    private readonly IHubContext iHubContext;

    private PostNotification()
        : this(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PostHub>())
    {
    }

    internal PostNotification(IHubContext iHubContext)
    {
        this.iHubContext = Guard.ArgumentNotNullAndReturn(iHubContext, "iHubContext");
    }

    public static PostNotification Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public void PostCreated(string action, PostResponse post)
    {
        var proxy = this.iHubContext.Clients.All;
        proxy.Invoke(action, post);
    }
}
}
```

My client side:

```
(function () {
Class.PostNotifications = function () {
    var parent = Class.Base(),
       _this = Util.extendObject(parent);

    _this.ReconnectionTime = 5000;


    _this.PostCreated_ObserverSubject = null;
    _this.PostHub = null;

    _this.ContentType = "";

    _this.constructor = function (contentType) {
        _this.ContentType = contentType;
        _this.startConnection();
        _this.setVars();
        _this.configurePostHub();
    };

    _this.setVars = function () {
        _this.PostHub = $.connection.postHub;
        _this.PostCreated_ObserverSubject = new Class.Patterns.Observer.Subject();
    };

    _this.configurePostHub = function () {
        _this.PostHub.client[_this.ContentType + 'Created'] = function (post) {                
            _this.PostCreated_ObserverSubject.notify(post);
        };
    };

    _this.whenPostCreated = function (functionDelegate) {
        if (functionDelegate !== undefined && functionDelegate !== null) {
            var json = {
                'UpdateDelegate': functionDelegate
            };
            var observer = new Class.Patterns.Observer.Observer();
            observer.init(json);
            _this.PostCreated_ObserverSubject.addObserver(observer);
        }
    };

    _this.startConnection = function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("connection stablish");
        }).fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }, _this.ReconnectionTime);
        });
    };

    return _this;
};
}());
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it happened to me also, we are stuck!